# Change Text Node via For Loop but resulted in Unexpected Identifier

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this problem that I think Javascript can solve and since I'm still learning the language that's another problem, so here I am asking for help.

I want to wrap the text node `I would like to opt in to receive future communication from.` in `<span class="something"></span>`.

My plan is to Loop it so that it will add span to all node text contents under an element

So I coded it and the console shows error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

**Orginal HTML**

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label class="gotowebinar-required" for="577271555173">I would like to opt in to receive future communication from</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

So I arrived at this I think terrible looking code that is seemingly not working and a variable freak.

**JS**

```
function changeEl(){
  var r = document.getElementsByClassName('gotowebinar-required').length;
  for (var i = 0; i <= r; i++){
    console.log(r);
    var m = '[';
    var n = ']';
    var b =  m+i+n;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('gotowebinar-required')b;
    var w = document.getElementsByClassName('gotowebinar-required')b.innerHTML;
    var y = x.innerHTML;
    var p = '<span style="font-weight: bold;"class="label_1">';
    var q = '</span>';
   x.innerHTML = p+w+q;
  };
};
changeEl();
```

In the end, what im looking for is

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label class="gotowebinar-required" for="577271555173">
        <span style="font-weight: bold;"class="label_1">I would like to opt in to receive future communication from.</span>
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

to all the elements that has a class of `gotowebinar-required`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant't use '[' and ']' to reference a item inside array like you did. If you use straight  [i] like code below you are good to go.

```
function changeEl(){
    var r = document.getElementsByClassName('gotowebinar-required').length;
    for (var i = 0; i < r; i++){
        console.log(r);
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName('gotowebinar-required')[i];
        var w = document.getElementsByClassName('gotowebinar-required')[i].innerHTML;
        var y = x.innerHTML;
        var p = '<span style="font-weight: bold;"class="label_1">';
        var q = '</span>';
        x.innerHTML = p+w+q;
    };
};
changeEl();
```

Comment: You are a hero! however, this shows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined
    at changeEl (<anonymous>:6:75)
    at <anonymous>:13:1"
can you enlighten me, i'm just afraid if this error will break something in there.

Comment: Sorry @user354355 I forgot to remove the <= inside the for loop. This is a common mistake and I totally go unnoticed. I updated my answer and I now you won't have any trouble :)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var m = '[';
> var n = ']';
> var b =  m+i+n;
> var x = document.getElementsByClassName('gotowebinar-required')b;
> ```

You can't put JS code in a variable and then smash it up any-old-where. Variables can't replace arbitary syntax.

The code betwen `[` and `]` can be an expression, but the `[` and `]` have to be typed explicitly:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('gotowebinar-required')[i];
```

---

> ```
> for (var i = 0; i <= r; i++){
> ```

You also need to loop until you reach the length instead of going one past it. `<=` should be `<`.

Answer (score 0):

There are good answers that explain why your code doesn't work. Instead of adding to that I would like to show you how you could wrap it into a nice reusable method.

```js
const 
  defaultPlaceholder = '{{text}}';


/**
 * Wraps the inner HTML of elements matching the selector into another HTML structure.
 *
 * @param {String} selector    A valid CSS selector matching the items to change.
 * @param {String} template    A string representation of the HTML structure in which the 
 *                             innerHTML of the matched elements should be placed.
 * @param {String} placeholder The string inside the template which should be replaced by the 
 *                             innerHTML of a matched element. When no value is provided, this
 *                             will have replace "{{text}}".
 */
function wrapInnerHTML(selector, template, placeholder = defaultPlaceholder) {
  const
    // Find the elements in the DOM matching the selector and convert the NodeList to an array.
    elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
   
  // Iterate over the elements
  elements.forEach(element => {
    const 
      // Create a new inner HTML string by replacing the placeholder in the template.
      newInnerHTML = template.replace(placeholder, element.innerHTML);
    // Replace the inner HTML of the element with the new content.
    element.innerHTML = newInnerHTML;
  });
}

wrapInnerHTML('.gotowebinar-required', '<label style="font-weight:bold" class="label_1">{{text}}</label>');
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="gotowebinar-required" for="577271555173">I would like to opt in to receive future communication from</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I've added some comments to better explain what is happening.

Answer (score -1):

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('gotowebinar-required')b;
var w = document.getElementsByClassName('gotowebinar-required')b.innerHTML;
```

Why is the letter b on the end there? If you delete the b your code runs fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/L9zv2ycz/

Also please please format your code :)

Comment: It runs without syntax errors. That is not the same as "fine". Using the_return_value_of_get_elements_by_class_name.innerHTML` is nonsense.

Comment: @Quentin OP asked why there were syntax errors, the code didn't run at all before. It runs now, not sure why I'm being downvoted

Comment: var b =  m+i+n; that is why there is a b so I could get like [i] so it will be [0] since i = 0. 

I did the best I could so I can present my code, other than that, not sure how to format it, I'm still a starter here.